# LINQ group by and combine as CSV

Tags: c#, linq

This is what I have

```
ID Value
1  Val1
1  Val2
3  Val3   
3  Val4
4  Val5
```

I need

```
ID Value
1  Val1, Val2
3  Val3, Val4
5  Val4
```

I am stuck at this point:

```
      var groups = Result.GroupBy(res => res.ID);      
      foreach (var group in groups)
      {                       
        foreach (var entry in group)
        {

        }
       }
```

How to get the result into a new anonymous type?

Note, I also need a concrete type that can be serialized as well.

EDIT: The final solution was like

```
[Serializable]   
public class KeyValueCSV 
{
    public decimal Key { get;set;}
    public string CSVValues { get;set;}
}

List<KeyValueCSV> kvCSVList = new List<KeyValueCSV>();
KeyValueCSV kvCSV;

          var groups = Result.GroupBy(res => res.ID);      
          foreach (var group in groups)
          {  kvCSV = new KeyValueCSV();  
            foreach (var entry in group)
            {
               kvCSV.id = entry.id;
               kv.CSVValues = enrty.Value + ", ";
            }
           kvCSVList.Add(kvCSV);
           }
```

Comment: So some guidance, you dont need an anonymous type, you just need to put it into a serializable type,  and why is your question titled 'LINQ group by and combine as CSV' I am guessing you forgot to mention that piece as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group has everything you need

```
[Serializable]   
public class KeyValueCSV 
{
    public string Key { get;set;}
    public List<string> CSVValues { get;set;}
}

 var groups = 
       Result.GroupBy(res => res.ID)
       .Select(x => new KeyValueCSV() { 
            Key=x.key, 
            CSVValues= string.Join(",", x.ToList()) 
           }
       );
```

---

You could also do it:

```
var groups = (
from res in Result
group r by res.ID
into grouping

select
   new  KeyValueCSV()
   {
     Key =  grouping.Key,
     CSVValues=  string.Join(",", grouping.ToList())
   }
);
```

**Let me know if I messed something up ;) I have been in the world of python recently so I might have managed to mix up some sytax...

Comment: I need a concrete object that can be serialized. Console.WriteLine does not help.

Comment: Then putting it into an anonymous type is not going to help you.  You need to explain what you want the final thing to look like.  Right now I just gave you what you asked for.... a grouping into an anonymous type.

Comment: Seems like the CSVValues is { ID = 1, Value = Val1 }, {ID = 2, Value = Val2} and 2nd query 'r' is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing Linq to Objects you can do this

```
from res in Result
group res by res.ID into grouping
select new
{
 ID = grouping.Key,
 Values = grouping.Select(r => r.Value).Aggregate((a,b) => a + ", " + b)
}
```